# Ubuntu server - record audio

Tags: ubuntu, audio

Is there any way to record audio on Ubuntu server? I've got Ubuntu on an old Acer Aspire 5520g but I'm not sure where to start with recording audio on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course - there are lots of programs out there which do this - most are fairly minimal - but [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) has lots of features, and works almost everywhere.

(If you can't get sound output working then you'll probably have problems with recording too)

Edit:

Or if you need a command line tool - [arecord](http://linux.die.net/man/1/arecord) comes bundled in the ALSA package

Comment: Does Audacity work on the CLI?

Comment: Don't think so - if you've got alsa confugred, try 'arecord'. See man page for more details

Comment: Thanks symcbean, I managed to get areacord, now onto the joy of finding sound drivers. Any chance you can delete the comment and post it as an answer so I can accept it? Cheers!